# where is the latest Synergy for Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, synergy

I use SynergyKM on my Mac OS X 10.5.7 MacBook Pro to share my keyboard with my Windows XP desktop.

On the Mac its recently stopped working.  Here's the log:

```
7/29/09 2:23:39 PM Synergyd[328] *** -[SDSynergyServerWrapper isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145930 
7/29/09 2:23:39 PM Synergyd[328] Exception raised during posting of notification. Ignored.  exception: '*** -[SDSynergyServerWrapper isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145930'  invoked observer method: '*** -[LCSStdIOTaskWrapper readCompletition:]'  observer: 0x146110  notification name: 'NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification'
```

I guess a recently system update broke it.  I went to go upgrade synergy, but it looks like the [SynergyKM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergykm/) project and the [original synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) projects are both dead (nothing released since v1.3.1 in 2006!).  Synergy is so useful, surely the project has been resurrected elsewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Synergy+ takes over where synergy left off.

http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/

Comment: oooh!  Wish I had known about that a couple weeks ago! :)

Comment: Also just found out about this a few days ago. Works on Snow Leopard!

Comment: Also just found out about Synergy+ a few days ago. Using it now. Works on Snow Leopard! Good to here there is active development again.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date: "Visit the new Synergy website. Synergy+ and Synergy have now combined efforts."

Answer (score 2):

I've just been using the original synergy (both Mac and Windows).  Just set it up a couple weeks ago.  Maybe it hasn't been updated in a while, but it still works just fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is out-of-date.  On http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/:

> Visit the new [Synergy website](http://synergy-foss.org/). Synergy+ and Synergy have now combined
>   efforts.

Note that my Mac keyboard didn't work on my Windows 7 machine with Synergy 1.3.8 (though the mouse did). [Downgrading to 1.3.6 solved the problem](http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/questions/963/mac-server-keyboad-does-not-work-on-windows-client?page=1#1157).

Answer (score 1):

I am happily using [SynergyKM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergykm/') on Lepoard. Yes it hasn't been updated but it works 100% with the existing Synergy windows binaries if you need to work cross platform.

I suppose, if it ain't broken it hasn't needed fixing.